# Characterization of topological spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Apparently, the following is an equivalent characterization of topological spaces: consider a relation $\ll$ on the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of a set $X$, with the following axioms:

1) $\emptyset\ll \emptyset$, $X\ll X$

2) If $A'\subseteq A\ll  B\subseteq B'$, then $A'\ll B'$

3) If $A\ll A'$, $B\ll B'$, then $A\cap B\ll A'\cap B'$

4) If $A_i\ll B_i$ for all $i\in I$ for some index set $I$, then $\bigcup_i A_i\ll \bigcup B_i$

5) If $A\ll B$ then $A\subseteq B$

Then there exists a unique topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ such that $A\ll B$ if and only if $A\subseteq \text{Int}(B)$.

Does anybody know a reference of this result? What would be a common way to cal the $\ll$ relation?

Comment: There were truly a lot of papers and even some books about variations on the theme of uniform spaces. While Bourbaki has studied them in a different style, there were pioneering papers by Y.Smirnov, in the style as above, then by others (perhaps there was an ambitious book by ,,, the name shows and escapes mi, like Csasard--a very poor approximation..., I think--Hungarian).

Comment: Also, the metrization theorems, first the original one by Alekandrov-Urysohn, then the ultimate by A.Archangielski, were somewhat in this style.

Comment: Y.Smirnov, and even another Soviet mathematician before him gave it a start, considered *nearness*. ****** And would the mentioned book author was Csaszar?--a better approximation? Yes, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019713018007

Comment: Those axioms are similar to the axioms for a proximity space although axioms 4 is definitely not satisfied by proximities since for proximities the union must be finite. See the book on proximity spaces by Naimpally, Somashekhar A.; Warrack, Brian D. for more information about these structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the relevant axioms on Csaszar, under the name of a simple perfect topogeneous structure, which is apparently equivalent to a topology. There is an axiom missing though, that states that $A\ll B$ implies there is some $C$ such that $A\ll C\ll B$. Wlod AA, if you make your comment into an answer, I'll select it as best answer.

Comment: I've heard $A \ll B$ spoken as "$A$ lies well inside $B$".

Comment: Paragraph 8.4 in Engelking dicusses this under proximity  spaces, which are quite related. He calls $\ll$ strong inclusion.